# Parallelize for-loop in c++ - memory error

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, memory-leaks, openmp, codeblocks

I am trying to parallelize a for-loop in C++, but every time I try to use this loop for a larger data set, I get this error:
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

For small data sets the loop works and for larger sets the initialization works but after this I get memory errors.
I am using Codeblocks and the GNU GCC Compiler.
In this loop I want to run several iterations of an optimiziation evolutionary heuristic.
I am using openmp and tried to put the variables which are used in several threads in private.

```
#include <omp.h>

void search_framework(Data &data, Solution &best_s)
{
    vector<Solution> pop(data.p_size);
    vector<Solution> child(data.p_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < data.p_size; i++)
    {
        pop[i].reserve(data);
        child[i].reserve(data);
    }

    // parent index in pop
    vector<tuple<int, int>> p_indice(data.p_size);
    bool time_exhausted = false;
    int run = 1;
    #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(pop, pop_fit, pop_argrank, child, child_fit, child_argrank, p_indice)
    for (int run = 1; run <= data.runs; run++)
    {
        run++;
        int no_improve = 0;
        int gen = 0;
        initialization(pop, pop_fit, pop_argrank, data);
        local_search(pop, pop_fit, pop_argrank, data);

        while (!termination(no_improve, data))
        {
            gen++;
            // printf("---------------------------------Gen %d---------------------------\n", gen);
            no_improve++;
            // select parents
            select_parents(pop, pop_fit, p_indice, data);
            // do local search for children
            local_search(child, child_fit, child_argrank, data);
            // replacement
            replacement(pop, p_indice, child, pop_fit, pop_argrank, child_fit, child_argrank, data);
            // update best
            argsort(pop_fit, pop_argrank, data.p_size);
            update_best_solution(pop[pop_argrank[0]], best_s, used, run, gen, data);
            if (data.tmax != NO_LIMIT && used > clock_t(data.tmax))
            {
                time_exhausted = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (time_exhausted) run = data.runs;
    }
}
```

Edited: This is the part where pop etc.. is initialized:

```
void initialization(vector<Solution> &pop, vector<double> &pop_fit, vector<int> &pop_argrank, Data &data)
{
    int len = int(pop.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        pop[i].clear(data);
    }
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   {
            data.lambda_gamma = data.latin[i];
            new_route_insertion(pop[i], data);
   }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        pop_fit[i] = pop[i].cost;
    }
    argsort(pop_fit, pop_argrank, len);
}
```

Comment: That error usually means you are accessing memory you do not own - e.g. wrong indexing. Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger or inspecting the core dump? It will tell you which access is problematic.

Comment: When I am debugging it is working fine and I have a different memory space for the private variables in every thread. I think my program is not executed in parallel when I am debugging. How can I test it when it is working in parallel?

Comment: please provide a [mre].

Comment: Since you're using C++, use `.at()` indexing. That will tell you where you go wrong.

Comment: Neither `pop[i]` not `child[i]` have any initialized elements, they only have memory reserved. If you don't later initialize them then access is still undefined behavior. The problem is somewhere in the code not shown.

Answer (score 0):

You duplicated for increasing `run`
One `for (int run = 1; run <= data.runs; run++)`
and right below `run++`
I don't know what is the 'Data' in this case, but I guess this is unstable.
If not, I guess the type of `data.runs` is `unsigned long`, be careful with
`for (int run = 1; run <= data.runs; run++)`
The range of `int` is "-2147483648 to 2147483647", if the value of `data.runs` out of `int` range, this is very dangerous, it may create an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it. But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the stack size for each OMP thread using the OMP_STACKSIZE environment variable.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.1.0/libgomp/OMP_005fSTACKSIZE.html

I think the private data structures get put on the stack.  So increasing the problem size will eventually exceed the reserved stack space.